# Is it the formal writing to use double adverbs like "very very" or "really really"?

Tags: adverbs, writing, formality, intensifiers

I am writing a letter, I want to mention a thing by using double adverbs.
For instance,

*it is **really really** cool,
it is **very very** nice.*

Something Like that,
is it the formal writing or not?

Comment: I would avoid it in formal writing. I'd also avoid 'cool'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Fox Kilmeade

> If you have a cloud over Europe that extends across the Atlantic throughout the summer, that is going to be ***very very*** bad news for the president.

From USA Today (though a speech)

> Very early on we made spoons out of agate, ***very very*** thin and very delicate; they were Russian silver spoons where we altered some of the design to give them more shape, but they were very nice because the agate was exceptional and we made a series of those

And *many more* results from COCA say that it's okay. However, I think it depends on the writer's style.

---

Another style that I came across is worth noting. Using a 'comma' between two very's. One such instance is from [the NY Times.](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/05/11/interest-rates-are-still-very-low/?_r=0)

> But it's important to understand that 0.6 percent is still **a very, very** low rate by any historical standard.

---

In your question, you are using 'very very cool' or 'very very nice' -it seems you are writing to someone in an informal way. in this context, I'm pretty sure that you can go for it! But hey, don't exceed 'two'!

Comment: That 2nd example is a bit painful, 5 verys in one sentence! Looks like it was written by a child with limited vocabulary. I was always told at school, that if I couldn't think of a better word than 'nice', I needed to be writing about something else; 'very nice' would have had me at the front of the class explaining why ;) The first example is acceptable, for emphasis, but I'd still mark it "could try harder" ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'd say it's 100% certain Maulik's example #2 is (relatively informal) ***speech***. Even a halfway competent *writer* would almost certainly realise how awkward/ungainly *very very thin and very delicate* is phrased. There are a couple of obvious ways to "fix" it, depending on the exact nuance of meaning intended. 1: Delete the third *very* (and in speech, minimise inter-word gaps in *thin and delicate*, so the initial repeated *very very* applies to *both* attributes). 2: Resequence to *very delicate and very very thin* so the *last* quality mentioned gets the emphatic repetition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, you are right. Mentioned! But do you suggest replacing it with some other example?

Comment: Have an upvote, Maulik! I think it's important on ELL that we should keep reminding questioners about the different standards normally considered applicable to speech as opposed to writing. Particularly, ***formal** writing*, which OP specifically mentioned here. Your newly-added final example is also good, because it shows how the repetitive format (including that all-important comma) can reasonably be used in (relatively) formal writing.