# Using two adverbs, both to give a degree to an adjective

Tags: adverbs

I've read some of my possible duplicates: [two-adverbs-in-a-row-with-ly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149634/two-adverbs-in-a-row-with-ly), [two-consecutive-adverbs-ending-in-ly](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/195538/two-consecutive-adverbs-ending-in-ly), and [is-it-the-formal-writing-to-use-double-adverbs-like-very-very-or-really-reall](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56925/is-it-the-formal-writing-to-use-double-adverbs-like-very-very-or-really-reall). My question is focused on the usage of two different adverbs to give a great degree to an adjective.

The sentence I took from my exercise book is:

> You always seem **so absolutely** contented with life.

Is it not necessary to put 2 adverbs there? I mean either -

> You always seem **so** contented with life.

or

> You always seem **absolutely** contented with life.

is enough, right? Does the sentence sound natural and correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's a matter of degrees:

> You always seem contented with life. (lowest)
> You always seem **so** contented with life.
> You always seem **absolutely** contented with life.
> You always seem **so absolutely** contented with life. (highest)

All sentences are proper and sound proper, the last one being less formal.